# Problem verifying trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

I am really struggling to understand a step in a question verifying trig identities the problem is the following:

$\tan2(x) -2\tan(x)\sin^2(x) = \sin2(x)$

This is what I have done so far.

$$\tan2(x) -2\tan2(x)\sin^2(x) = \frac{\sin2(x)}{\cos2(x)} - 2 \frac{\sin2(x) \sin^2x}{\cos2(x)}$$

I know the step which is supposed to be done after this as I have the answer sheet but I don't understand it.

$$\tan2(x) -2\tan2(x)\sin^2(x) = \frac{\sin2(x)}{\cos2(x)} - 2 \frac{\sin2(x)[\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2(x)]}{\cos2(x)}$$

I can't understand how  $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2(x)$ I'm quite consufed by this, I know that $\sin^2(x) = 1-\cos^2(x)$ but how do I go on from there. Am I missing something fundamental here? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know the cosine addition formula?

Comment: In LaTeX, if you type \tan instead of tan, the trigonometric angles wouldn't appear all italicized as they currently are. This applies to all trigonometric functions (and many other math expressions).

Comment: You made a mistake, when you replaced $2\tan(x)$ by $2\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}$

Comment: I missed the 2 in the $ 2\tan2(x) $

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=\dfrac\pi4$ to refute the proposition.

At best
$$\tan^2x-\sin^2x$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}-\sin^2x$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin^2x(1-\cos^2x)}{\cos^2x}$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin^4x}{\cos^2x}=\tan^2x\sin^2x$$

Answer (score 0):

There are three expressions for $\cos(2x)$

$$\cos(2x)=\cos(x+x)$$
$$=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$$

$$=(1-\sin^2(x))-\sin^2(x)$$
$$=1-2\sin^2(x)$$
$$=\cos^2(x)-(1-\cos^2(x))$$
$$=2\cos^2(x)-1$$

So

$$2\sin^2(x)=1-\cos(2x)$$